# Can I populate a listView with a nested array using Simpleadapter and hashmap?

Tags: android, listview, multidimensional-array, hashmap, simpleadapter

I'm trying to populate a ListView using a HashMap and a SimpleAdapter from a nested array with 12 columns and 12 rows

So here is my code

```
try {
    String [][] array2 = new String[cursor.getCount()][cursor.getColumnCount()];
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for (int i =0; i<cursor.getCount();i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cursor.getColumnNames().length; j++) {
            String uname = cursor.getString(j);
            array2[i][j]=uname;
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

and then the simple adapter with hashmap

```
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.item2, R.id.item3, R.id.item4, R.id.item5, R.id.item6, R.id.item7, R.id.item8 ,R.id.item9, R.id.item10, R.id.item11, R.id.item12};
List<HashMap<String,String>> fillMaps = (List<HashMap<String, String>>) new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

for(int i = 0; i<10;i++){
    HashMap<String,ArrayList> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();

}

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.grid_item, array2, to);
```

when I try this I get an error

> `SimpleAdapter(android.content.Context, java.util.List<? extends java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?>>, int, java.lang.String[], int[])`' in `android.widget.SimpleAdapter` cannot be applied to 
>   `(com.example.thevenom1215.prueba.MainActivity, java.util.List<java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>>, int, java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String>, int[])`

Or I thought that I could convert the nested array to a simple array is that possible? If so how can I accomplish that? I tried this

```
String from [] = new String from[252]:
from[0]= array[0][1]+"|"+array[0][2]+"|"+array[0][3]+......+array[0][12];
```

but it doesn't work.

In the `array2`, which is `array2[12][21]`, every row has 12 columns, which are information of a person, for example `(name, age)`

```
Cesar Joel Gurrola, xx
```

The first row of the array is: `[Cesar, Joel, Gurrola, xx]`

I need that in an array because further in my code I need `String` by `String` and not a whole String `"Cesar, Joel, Gurrola, xx"`

Sql query

```
sql="select b.CVE_CONTR, r.NO_RECIBO , a.NOM_SOLICIT ,r.NO_PARCIAL ,r.SDO_TOTAL, r.STS_PAGO ,a.AP_PATSOLICIT,a.AP_MATSOLICIT, " +
                            "f.DESCRIPCION, b.NO_PARCIALID , b.PAGO_PARCIAL, b.TOT_APAG from MFRF_M_SOLICITANTES a, MFRF_M_CONTPREV_H b, MFRF_M_CONTPREV_D_RECGEN_2 r," +
                            "C_PAQUETE f , C_PARCIALIDADES g, MFRF_C_COLONIAS c where b.CVE_CONTR = '"+etnumcontrato.getText().toString() + "' and r.STS_PAGO in ('1','10','11','12')" +
                            "and c.ID_COLONIA = a.ID_COLONIA  and f.ID_PAQUETE = b.ID_PAQUETE and g.ID_PARCIALIDAD = b.ID_PARCIAL AND a.ID_SOLICIT = b.ID_SOLICITANTE  ";
```

Comment: First, why are you doing this? Use a Java class with your 12 fields. And load those into an `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: Secondly, you should see that the `array2` parameter you gave must be a `String[]`, not an arraylist or a 2D array.

Comment: And last `new String from[252]:` isn't correct java syntax. `new String[252]:` is.

Comment: I'm doing this because I need every single item in the array2 and not the whole Arraylist 
If I use a class to save de data for example data() with 12 fields wouldn't I be only capable of saving one String? I mean I can only save one String at a time

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by one string. You define a custom xml layout and you "bind" that object to any view you want there. Maybe you should include a screeenshot or drawing of what you want.

Comment: In the array2 there is a information: array2[12][21], every row has 12 columns, which are information of a person, for example my name Cesar Joel Gurrola then my age xx years, so the row 0 of the array is:
array2[0][0] Cesar
array2[0][1] Joel
array2[0][3] Gurrola
array2[0][4] xx

I need that because further in my code I need String by String and not a whole String " Cesar, Joel, Gurrola, xx"

Comment: Is this stored in Sqlite? Essentially, you are describing a database table. And you need to "expand" each "nested" value, or convert to a singlular object, such as a String

Comment: yes it is, and yes I need to, but I don't know how

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Now, can you please clean up the code in the comments on my answer, and describe what things work and don't work this time, but in the question, not the comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall, I wouldn't recommend this.

```
String [][] array2 = new String[cursor.getCount()][cursor.getColumnCount()];
```

An adapter displays **one** row-item at a time, not the whole table.

---

I would instead recommend a `CursorAdapter` since you do have a `Cursor` object, but I'll continue with a `SimpleAdapter`.

First, you need to create an XML layout, let it be named `item_layout.xml`. It contains all the Views that you want to bind the row from the database to. I believe these must all be TextViews for a SimpleAdapter.

```
String[] from = new String[] {"rowid", "fname", "mname", "lname"};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.item1, R.id.item2, R.id.item3, R.id.item4 };
```

Then, loop over the rows of the cursor, and pull out the necessary information into a List of HashMaps. Note: this is **one row** of data each time that we are looping over the cursor results. And, as described earlier, you only have TextViews, so you can only store String values.

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
final int rows = cursor.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("rowid", "" + i);
    map.put("fname", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("fname"));
    map.put("mname", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("mname"));
    map.put("lname", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("lname"));

    fillMaps.add(map);
    cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

Now that you have looped over all the rows of the data and are satisfied with that data, you just set the adapter.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, 
        R.layout.item_layout, 
        from, to);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I tried this but gives me an error: Index -1 requested, with a size of 21

Comment: Want to be more descriptive than that? I'm willing to edit the post if you tell me what error this causes.

Comment: @CesarJoelGurrola Right... `cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow` needs to be given a correct column name from the database. You didn't show your schema, so you can't simply copy this answer as-is.

Comment: I know, and I copied the column name directly from the query because that error is because the column doesn't exist right?

Comment: String [] from = new String[]{"CVE_CONTR","NO_RECIBO","NOM_SOLICIT","NO_PARCIAL","SDO_TOTAL","STS_PAGO","AP_PATSOLICIT","AP_MATSOLICIT","DESCRIPCION",
                                "NO_PARCIALID","PAGO_PARCIAL","TOT_APAG"};
                        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.c1, R.id.c2, R.id.c3, R.id.c4, R.id.c5, R.id.c6, R.id.c7 ,R.id.c8, R.id.c9, R.id.c10, R.id.c11,R.id.c12, R.id.c13, R.id.c14};
                        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

Comment: final int rows = cursor.getCount();
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                fillMaps.add(map);
                            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
                                map.put("rowid"," "+i);

Comment: map.put("CVE_CONTR", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CVE_CONTR")));
                                map.put("NO_RECIBO",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NO_RECIBO")));
                                map.put("NOM_SOLICIT",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NOM_SOLICIT")));
                                map.put("NO_PARCIAL",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NO_PARCIAL")));

Comment: I'm going to stop you right there.. Please **do not** use the comments for code.

Comment: and so......

     map.put("TOT_APAG",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TOT_APAG")));
                                fillMaps.add(map);
                                cursor.moveToNext();
                            }


but I got that error, when I was using the code from above(the one of the question) I solve that error by adding a element to the array so the array wouldn't be empty and I tried that here but didn't work

Comment: You are mostly likely getting an error through the usage of `getString` when you are trying to access a column that is not a String type in the database. You need to use `getInt`, for example, for number columns

Comment: so I must change the HashMap because if I change getString for getInt I marks as a synax error

Comment: @CesarJoelGurrola The HashMap must contain strings. That cannot be changed. You can, however, use `String.valueOf()` on a Integer value to get the String.

Comment: when I debug this, it returns me null
map.put("CVE_CONTR", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("CVE_CONTR"))); 

the column name on the Database is CVE_CONTR is the same so why would it return me a null? any idea? also I tried cvecontr=cursor.getString0, and again it is null so what could be causing it?

Comment: You could simply have a null value in the database :)

Comment: but why when I try this 
ArrayList<String> datos = new ArrayList<String>();
int i = 0;
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        datos.add(i, cursor.getString(0) + "," + cursor.getString(1) + "," + cursor.getString(2) + "," +  cursor.getString(3) + ","+ cursor.getString(4)+ ","+ cursor.getString(5)+ ","+ cursor.getString(6)+ ","+ cursor.getString(7)+ ","+ cursor.getString(8)+ ","+ cursor.getString(9)+ ","+ cursor.getString(10)+ ","+ cursor.getString(11));  
i++; } 
it does return me a list of values and noone is empty